# Activities created with Share Link Popup not shown in activities.list API-query

Tags: google-plus

When I share a link via the share-link endpoint [https://plus.google.com/share?url=*link-url*](https://plus.google.com/share?url=_link-url_)
(as described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/?hl=en#sharelink-endpoint)) and then request the activities of the account I shared with using the Google Plus API, the resulting activity does not show (even though it was created and exists on the activity-feed)

Neither `activities.list` nor `activities.search` shows the post.

Is this intended behaviour/ are these shared links filtered?

Comment: What is the visibility of the activities posted? Are they public or limited to specific people/circles?

Comment: The posts are public and the request via API is also requesting public posts

Comment: Do you have an example post that is not visible via activities.list?